# #define at preprocessor - is it just copy paste in calculations?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

If I have

```
#define NUM (30 * 60)
```

does the pre-processor copy paste `(30 * 60)` to the code, or does it write 1800 anywhere `NUM` appears in the code ?

Comment: From where `300` comes ?

Answer (score 2):

## The Answer is `( 30 * 60 )` which is (probably) computed at compile time

As others have said, the preprocessor simply replaces the defined token with the text of its definition. It is then entirely up to the compiler itself to notice any arithmetic (such as `30*60`) that can be performed at compile time.

In your example, all eligible instances of `NUM` in your source file will simply be replaced by the text `( 30 * 60 )`.

And that is the simple answer to the direct question you asked. But there are couple more issues that are worth exploration.

## A common pitfall avoided

The text replacement performed by the preprocessor is literal. That is, the preprocessor does not understand almost any of the syntax of the C language. So it is possible that the result doesn't mean what you expect. For example, if you had

```
#define N 30 + 60
int a = N * 2;
```

the preprocessed text would read `int a = 30 + 60 * 2;` which does not make `a` be 180 as might be expected from `N*2`. Rather, due to precedence `a` becomes 150.

The solution to this is to always use enough parenthesis in the expanded text, and your writing `( 30 * 60 )` is an example of this best practice. When you begin to use macros that include formal parameters, you will discover that judicious use of parenthesis can be extremely important to avoid surprises.

## Let's look at cpp

But I wanted to go beyond the simple answer, and try to show you how to explore the behavior of the preprocessor yourself.

For code as simple as in your question, knowing that it is a simple text substitution should be enough to predict what will happen. But as you begin to use more complicated features of the preprocessor (starting with macros that take parameters) occasionally you will want to debug your prepreprocessor usage. To do that, it is often easiest to run the preprocessor without also compiling and running any code.

(Similarly, sometimes you will want to know what the compiler itself did, and for that it is useful to compile to assembly language without also creating a binary and executing the code. We'll take a look under that hood in the next section.)

The preprocessor is historically a separate program that was run by the compiler driver command on the source file and before the first pass of the compiler proper. In modern compiler implementations, the preprocessor is not usually implemented as a separate executable, but for historical reasons it can still be invoked without compilation.

The usual name for the preprocessor is `cpp`. In the extremely commonly available GCC compiler suite, it can also be invoked as `gcc -E`. In both cases, `cpp` will read a file named on its command line, or read `stdin` if no file is named, and write its output to `stdout`. That output will usually be decorated with `#line` directives so that the compiler can blame the right source file. You can usually turn that off with a command line option, which is `-P` for the GCC implementation.

Given this source code:

```
#define NUM (30 * 60)
int n = NUM * 42;
char *str = "NUM";
```

We can feed it through the preprocessor like so and see the output immediately:

```
C:\...>cpp -P q19987548.c
int n = (30 * 60) * 42;
char *str = "NUM";

C:\...>
```

Note also that the substitution does not occur inside a string literal. Some much older compilers did replace text in strings, but not since the first C standard was adopted.

## But when was `(30 * 60) * 42` computed?

Taking this one step further, we can ask the compiler to show us its generated assembly code, and use that to discover whether it computed the expression at compile time or not. In many C compilers, this is done using the `-S` option, as it is in GCC. Using GCC targeting the x86 on Windows as a typical example, we can compile the above code fragment, and get the following assembly output:

```
        .file   "q19987548.c"
        .globl  _n
        .data
        .align 4
_n:
        .long   75600
        .globl  _str
        .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
        .ascii "NUM\0"
        .data
        .align 4
_str:
        .long   LC0
```

As can be seen, this code fragment declares a location named `_n` and fills it with the constant 75600 which is exactly `30 * 60 * 42`. So it clearly was computed by the compiler in this case.

In general, when using the usual optimizations for your target, you should assume that the compiler knows what it is doing and not worry too much about this level of detail.

## Stepping off the deep end

The C preprocessor can be used to for some rather startling tricks, despite not being a complete programming language.

Since it is so decoupled from the C language itself, it can be used to process source code for other languages. I've seen it used to generate man pages and other documents in `nroff` and `troff`. Any source text that is compatible with its rules for tokenization and accepting of its injection of white space and removal of C comments can be processed with it.

Comment: This is a really simple question and obviously a beginner. Bombarding them with all this complex, barely relevant information isn't really helpful. Furthermore, there is no mentioning of gcc in the question.

Comment: IMHO, context is always helpful. Often more so for the next person who finds the question through searching. SO *usually* respects that. But perhaps my attempt to show rather than tell wandered too far from the context of the question.

Comment: @Lundin, while I disagree with the vehemence felt be some against my answer, I do agree that it lacked structure. To that end I've substantially re-written it to separate exploration of possibility from the simple answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor replaces instance of `NUM` in your code with precisely what you specify - `(30 * 60)`.  The compiler may (almost certainly will) later optimise this to `1800`, saving you the runtime calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NUM (30 * 60)
```

will replace `NUM` exactly with `(30 * 60)`.

That is the reason why something like this can sometimes lead to a terrible & stupid erratic behavior:

```
#define H  0.1f
#define H2 2.f*H
```

and now in the actual code that is supposed to calculate the derivative of a function `f` of order O(h^2):

```
float num_dev = (f(x+H)-f(x-H))/H2
```

**If** the preprocessor **would** calculate the result of `2.f*H` before substitution, everything would be in order.

**But** since the preprocessor just substitutes `H2` as `2.f*H` this would give wrong result.

```
float num_dev = ((f(x+H)-f(x-H))/2.f)*H
```

(I added the new `()` to make my point clear, the compiler won't do so.)

Therefore, it is always a **very good idea to put parentheses** around the expression, as you did.

```
 #define H2 (2.f*H)
```

Here is an actual example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define H 0.1f
#define H2 2.f*H

int main(void) {

    float a = (4.f-2.f)/H2;

    float b = (4.f-2.f)/(H2);

    printf("%f   %f\n", a, b);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
0.100000   10.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

**Preprocessing is defined in terms of token substitution.** When the token `NUM` is found, it is replaced by the 5-token sequence `(`, `30`, `*`, `60`, `)`. The actual rules are slightly more involved, since you may have `NUM` also appear in the replacmement (where it will NOT be substituted again), but that is the big picture.

As for multiplying, most if not all compilers, will do the multiplication for you and use 1800 in the generated code.

Comment: To be pedantic, the whitespace between the tokens is also included in the substitution. There are a few operations where it can become significant.

Comment: The detailed significance of whitespace was a deliberate change from the K&R era preprocessor and the first ANSI C Standard preprocessor. One often was able to do token pasting with `A/**/B` but that got "clarified" to always result in the text `A B` and *not* `AB`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) you can use the -E flag to display the preprocessor output.  You can test the behavior of your own compiler with this one-liner:

```
$ { echo "#define NUM (30 * 60)"; echo "int a = NUM;" ; } | gcc -E -
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"

int a = (30 * 60);
$
```

Comment: Programming by experimentation is as useful as proof by example in mathematics.

Comment: @Jens - Cute analogy - but I don't entirely agree.  While I'm sure you write perfect bug-free programs first time every time, my programming style involves a great deal of experimentation before I get things working the way I want them.

Comment: Experimentation is how we learn what is possible in general. And when an experiment yields an unexpected result, we learn about the boundaries of our understanding.